# How do I resolve, "The application which this project type is based on was not found." error?

Tags: android, visual-studio, plugins, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to launch the `ServiceStack.AndroidIndie` solution to use with the tutorial. I'm trying to enable the [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) Api in my Android app; However, I'm receiving the following error, upon trying to open the project file:

```
Migration Report -

Overview

Project Path                            Errors  Warnings    Messages
ServiceStack.Client.AndroidIndie.csproj     1       0           0
ServiceStack.Interfaces.AndroidIndie.csproj 1       0           0
ServiceStack.Text.AndroidIndie.csproj       1       0           0
ServiceStack.AndroidIndie.sln               0       0           1

ServiceStack.Client\ServiceStack.Client.AndroidIndie.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. 
ServiceStack.Interfaces\ServiceStack.Interfaces.AndroidIndie.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found.
..\..\ServiceStack.Text\src\ServiceStack.Text\ServiceStack.Text.AndroidIndie.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found.
ServiceStack.AndroidIndie.sln: The solution file does not require migration.
```

I am of course using the latest version downloaded of the official GitHub page, also synced with ServiceStack directly through windows GitHub app.

Tried launching projects in both VS 2012 and VS 2013. Same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has happened to other projects aswell, not only ServiceStack.. Anyone has any idea how to resolve them?

Comment: It would seem that opening the project in Xamarin works,
And apparently It should be able to open this project in Visual Studio if the XAMARIN plugin for visual studio was installed.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall Xamarin but no plugin is available for me in Visual studio and I cannot find anything on google.. any tips?

Comment: Hi Myslex did you get this working?

Comment: @Scott Yes! Late yesterday I got it working. It would seem that the Visual Studio plugin from Xamarin was not installed correctly and once I had installed the plugin I was able to open and build the solution.

HOWEVER as you pointed out earlier Xamarin for VS is not free.. 
Therefor I decided to use the "free" libraries and with that I did not need to open the project files.. 


Again a HUGE thanks for your help Scott, AGAIN.
Sincerely yours,

Comment: Awesome glad you have it working. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio is not free. It is currently only available with a Xamarin Business plan ($999 p/a) or Enterprise plan ($1899 p/a). See the [Xamarin Store](https://store.xamarin.com/)

You can confirm if the plugin is installed and active by:

1. Opening Visual Studio
2. Choose *Tools* Menu
3. Choose *Extensions & Updates*
4. You should see, under *Installed > All*

   [image]

   Check it's not disabled.

If it's not there then you will need to to this:

1. Visit [xamarin.com/download](http://xamarin.com/download)
2. Choose *Download Xamarin for Windows*
3. Run the installer on windows. Select the Android Components. (add iOS if required). It will probably take about 30 minutes to install.
4. Launch Visual Studio when the installion completes
5. Open the project, this dialog should be shown

   [image: Dialog]
6. Create a Xamarin account and activate the 30 day trial or Enter your existing Xamarin Business/Enterprise credentials.

You will be able to open the project in Xamarin Studio (as you have discovered), for free, without any issue.